# Avoiding the "Non-constant fields should not be visible" code analysis warning

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I have an object that has a list of business rules that are checked when the object is validated.

At the top of the class I create static fields of type BusinessRule as shown below:-

```
public class SyncFile : Waterstons.Patterns.Entities.BaseEntity<Guid>
{        
    public static BusinessRule NameRequiredRule = new BusinessRule("Name", "The audit file must have a name");
    ....


    protected override void Validate()
    {
        if (Id == default(Guid))
        {
            AddBrokenRule(IdRequiredRule);
        }
        ....
```

This leads to code analysis complaining that I shouldn't have public fields unless they are const. I'm not sure I can define them as const however based on how I'm using them.

So is there a better way to approach this? Should I expose them as properties as below instead?

```
    public static BusinessRule _nameRequiredRule = new BusinessRule("Name", "The audit file must have a name");
    public static BusinessRule Test
    {
        get { return _nameRequiredRule; }
    }
```

Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change your static field declaration to this

```
 public static readonly BusinessRule NameRequiredRule = new BusinessRule("Name", "The audit file must have a name");
```

So to make sure public field won't change during execution. Note also to make `BusinessRule` class immutable, so that not only reference can't be changed in `NameRequiredRule` but also instance contents can't be changed during runtime.

If you can't enforce immutability - consider declaring `NameRequiredRule` static field as private and create a static property.

```
private static BusinessRule _nameRequiredRule = new BusinessRule("Name", "The audit file must have a name");
public static BusinessRule NameRequiredRule
{
    get { return _nameRequiredRule; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have made the Business rules properties immutable, but the static analyser can't tell, so it complains that I've possibly made a mutable object readonly. I have to disable the warning if the object is immutable. Shame it doesn't detect that.

Comment: @RossDargan if `BusinessRule` but property is not marked with `readonly` - you still change change an instance of `NameRequiredRule` just by reassigning another created rule to `NameRequiredRule`

Comment: I have marked it as readonly, it was marked as readonly when it gave the above warning. The exact error is "Remove the read-only designation from 'SyncFile.UploadedByRequiredRule' or change the field to one that is an immutable reference type. If the reference type 'BusinessRule' is, in fact, immutable, exclude this message"

Comment: Just the one built into VS2012